# Import XML data into R automatically

Tags: xml, r

I'm using XML data to import a set of numbers, calculate a value depending on those numbers, for instance their mean or standard deviation, and then store that value into a CSV file.

The problem is that I'm currently doing it manually and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this automatically in order to handle several XML files.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right
Use the `XML` package. a function called xmlToDataFrame
Do the calculations in R and export the output as a DF

Comment: Just be careful. On my Windows machine there's a pretty serious memory leak in the XML package that forces me to restart R after a few importing a few XML files. I notified the author back in Oct '13 but he's been "very, very busy."